# Producing unnecessary html tags - Angular

Tags: html, angular

NgIf and NgFor in same element to reduce elements in the DOM

Situation I have:

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
    <content *ngIf="i < someVar"></content>
</li>
```

Situation I want:

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index" *ngIf="i < someVar">
    <content></content>
</li>
```

I want to have the `ngIf` and `ngFor` tag in the same element, because I don't want the DOM to be filled with 'list item' tags.

Is there a way to do something like this, or do I just have to live with it?

Comment: you can not use *ngFor and *ngIf in same tag. You need to use ng-template for if-else content rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use multiple structural directives (like ngIf, ngFor, ngSwitch) in a single element. Use `ng-container` instead.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="i < someVar">
    <content ></content>
  </ng-container>
</li>

ng-container doesn't get rendered at runtime, so your html will look like:

<li> <content> </content> </li>
<li> <content> </content> </li>
<li> <content> </content> </li>
<li> <content> </content> </li>...
```

The reason why Angular doesn't allow to add more than one structural directive is given by the Angular doc:

> Someday you'll want to repeat a block of HTML but only when a
>   particular condition is true. You'll try to put both an *ngFor and an
>   *ngIf on the same host element. Angular won't let you. You may apply only one structural directive to an element.
>
> The reason is simplicity. Structural directives can do complex things
>   with the host element and its descendents. When two directives lay
>   claim to the same host element, which one takes precedence? Which
>   should go first, the NgIf or the NgFor? Can the NgIf cancel the effect
>   of the NgFor? If so (and it seems like it should be so), how should
>   Angular generalize the ability to cancel for other structural
>   directives?
>
> There are no easy answers to these questions. Prohibiting multiple
>   structural directives makes them moot. There's an easy solution for
>   this use case: put the *ngIf on a container element that wraps the
>   *ngFor element. One or both elements can be an ng-container so you don't have to introduce extra levels of HTML.

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose use `ng-container`:

```
<ng-conainer *ngIf="someCondition"> 
    <li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index" >
         <content></content>
    </li>
 </ng-container>
```

OR:

```
 <li *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index" >
      <content *ngIf="someCondition"></content>
 </li>
```

Comment: You forgot to replace </ng-container> with </li>.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks for the your attention. I’ve updated my reply. :)